# sudo gedit /etc/etter.conf shows empty file

Tags: gedit

when I open (etter.conf) to make some changes using the command :

> sudo gedit /etc/etter.con
>   I got an empty file

Comment: `sudo /etc/etter.conf` should result in a `Permission denied` error, because it's not supposed to be executable. What exactly are you doing and what's the error message?

Comment: I actually fixed my problem, I had the wrong directory in my command, actually it's 'sudo gedit /etc/ettercap/etter.conf' thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the command to open a `.conf` file, you must call a text editor and you have the location wrong.

To open it in a terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/ettercap/etter.conf
```

or to open it in a GUI application

```
gksudo gedit /etc/ettercap/etter.conf
```

You can swap `gedit` for your favourite text editor.

Tested on Xubuntu 15.10

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! As you are a new user if this helps you please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and allow others to easily find this information